# Lines and dots on UV Editor

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

[image]

There are some weird dots and lines on the faces I select to resize the texture. I'm not sure how this has happened, and I think it's happened to me before as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: The texture is stretched, because the triangle dimensions in the UV map don't match the dimensions in geometry.

Comment: What do you mean by dots and lines? Do you mean this rectangular with white dots at the corners and one dot with line at the top of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

The white lines and dots are handles for the Transform tool you have selected (Spacebar, T) in the UV Editor. The orange line is the UV island for the selected face that somehow got flattened and rotated. I'd suggest unwrapping the face again (U, U in Edit Mode in 3D Viewport) to get correct UVs.

Here's an example of two faces with the same texture applied. The UVs for the one on the right have been flattened and rotated:

[image]